# ReferenceError: '...' is not defined

Tags: qml

New to QML (particularly using Felgo framework).  Trying to do something very easy in an older tutorial, but it seems like scope rules maybe changed (unlikely) or instructions I'm following missed something.  I've pasted simplified code below:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Felgo 3.0
    
Page {

        id: searchPage
    
        Column
        {
            id: contentCol
    
            AppTextField
            {
                id: search_input
     
                showClearButton: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("Search...")
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
                onTextChanged: showRecentSearches()
            }
    
            Row
            {
                spacing:contentPadding
               
    
                AppButton
                {
                    text: qsTr("Go!")
                    onClicked: search()
                    enabled: true
                }
    
            }
        }
    
        function showRecentSearches()
        {
            console.debug(search_input.text);
        }
    }
```

However when I run this, I get that "ReferenceError: search_input is not defined".  I know if I put it within the Column braces, it is within scope; however if I needed to make this global (as in the tutorial I'm following), having it within Page braces seems to hide the scope for search_input id tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough this error went away by restarting the Felgo Live Server.  It seems id tags are only reparsed from a restart.